# UIButton image doesn't change when tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I need to have an image button change to a different image when I tap it. Simple enough, and there are samples out there, but they don't work for me. This is what I tried following the examples:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 270, 200, 40.0);
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"butterfly3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clicked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Submit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[scrollView button];
```

Now, I notice that my button is set to perform its action on `UIControlEventTouchDown` so I added it to the "clicked" control states like this:

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clicked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

but the image still stays the same. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure its the right button? Where do you add the button to the view? What does your buttonPresses method look like?

Comment: When a button is tabbed it will actually use the `UIControlStateHighlighted` not `UIControlStateSelected` if you want to use the `UIControlStateSelected` state you will need to set `[button setSelected:YES];` otherwise just change `UIControlStateSelected` to `UIControlStateHighlighted` that will do the job for you.

Comment: propbably, because the `–...forState:` is not a multiple choice option, and the `UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted` value is `0x05` which is not a valid control state (there is no state defined for this value, regarding the _selected_ state is `0x04` and the _highlighted_ is `0x01`). the `UIControlEventTouchDown` is not even `UIControlState`, so that makes the things much worse only.

Comment: Why downvote, moments after I'm giving an honest answer as to what the problem was (see my answer below.) @PeterSegerblom comment put me on the right track and I found what was the issue. The downvote makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Eddy, the essential mistakes, you committed here, are still essential mistakes with or without down-voting.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code by this, and everything will work!

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clicked.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clicked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that my buttonPressed method did a long(ish) query on the main thread and for some reason the highlighting of the button doesn't work in such a case.

When I moved the query to a separate thread the highlight went back on.

For the sake of completion I'll bring the code here. Initially I was fetching objects through Parse.com API like this:

```
[myQuery findObjects]
```

This above does the query on the main thread and blocks everything else.

Then I changed it to fetching in a separate thread like this:

```
[myQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if(!error) {
            // whatever is needed to be done
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error while fetching objects %@", error.description);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside buttonPressed method set yourButton.selected = YES; Also set image as Miroslav mentioned.

Comment: thanks for answering. When I do as you and Miroslav suggest the image indeed change to the clicked.png, but I am only able to see it once I dismiss the tableView it opens. This is not what I need. All I want is just a button that behaves like a button: gets highlighted when it's tapped, so the user knows he/she tapped it, and then goes back to it's normal state. The simplest button behavior.

Comment: remove this line: [button setImage:[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clicked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are putting an event mask *UIControlEventTouchDown* that is being interpreted as a state mask in this line:

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clicked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

In fact I think you may not need this line at all, as you've already set the appropriate images. Try removing UIControlEventTouchDown from this line or comment out the whole line.